# Pass Checkboxes values to Html - Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, multidimensional-array, typescript2.0

I have the following:

```
checkboxList:any = [];

 ngOnInit(): void
 {
     this.service.getAllCheckboxes().subscribe((data) => {
         this.checkboxList = data;
      });
    //CheckboxList gives me
    {'name1','name2','name3','name4','name5'}

   //For edit purpose
    const myObjt = this.location.getState();
    this.myForm.pathValue({
    ArrayName: myObjt.chekcboxesArray,
  }
}
```

Where my ArrayName gives me {'name1', 'name2'}

HTML

```
<form class="form-standard" [formGroup]="myForm"
  <div *ngFor="let tag of checkboxList">
       <label>
         <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="{{tag.tagsName }}
              (change)="onChange(tag.tagsName, $event)">
                 {{tag.tagsName}}
        </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I pass the array of checkboxes from **ArrayName** to the form on HTML (angular 11) on edit mode.
(I want to see the checkboxes checked accordingly).
Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[attr.selected] = "yourNewFunction(tag)".` Create a new function that checks if the tag is present in your checked array